# Angular trying to append object data but it's always replacing

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to append data with the following code:

```
mydata;  

append(data) {

    var obj = { id: data };

    this.newObj = {...this.newObj, ...obj};

    alert(JSON.stringify(this.newObj));
}
```

Example usage:

```
append(1);
```

Then...

```
append(2);
```

My result is always just the replacing ... it's updating and not merging both results.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not using array instead ?

Comment: Do you want to have `{ id: 1, id: 2 }`? If so it's not possible, it's an invalid object. Properties must be exclusive.

Comment: I want to have this: [ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works perfectly. Why? Because objects key must be unique. So you can't have `{id:1, id2}`, this is invalid object.

You can use array instead and simply use `push` method:

```
class test
{
    newObj :Array<{}> = [];

  append(data:number) :void {
    var obj = { id: data };

    this.newObj.push(obj);

    alert(JSON.stringify(this.newObj));
 }
}
var l = new test();

l.append(1);
l.append(2);
```

Result is :`[ { id: 1 }, { id: 2 } ]`

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=13&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAuCmFYCgDezqegO3gdwHkAjAK2gC4BBAJ2rAE8AeVAXwD5oBeaAbQF0A3MgzQwABzHxsAEwAU0sLDDlsAVwC2ReNQCUFAG4B7AJbTo6LNGnwiqgOZ3tIzPrDVoh0l3PRT5K4pg0CxCznAAFsYQAHS4hKTRYqoQ4bKeJDqhlmAg2rCyAFIAygQActFI1MbYdsYAZvSysJExccQZmRgsyN2u7iDecXCI%20Z3IINHikjKyAIydE1NScgBMnUA)

Answer (score 1):

With your last comment, this should work. You should have an array declared outside the function as variables declared inside the function have a "function/block" scope. I would suggest you do some research before posting a question.

```js
let myData = [];
function append(data){
    var obj = { 'id': data };
    myData.push(obj);
    console.log(myData);
}

append(1);
append(2);
append(3);
```